# Outlook not displaying integer user-defined field in calendar (other types OK)

Tags: microsoft-outlook

My appointments have 3 custom fields (integer, string, systemtime) and they contain data. When displaying 'View/Current View/All appointments' the integer *TimeTellID* shows no data. Below is a screenshot of part of that view. I had modified the view through Customize current view/Fields and then clicked 'New field' 3 times:

[image]

To verify, if I 'Remove' the field so that it moves back to the left column I can see the properties:

[image]

This happens in all (4) mailboxes that I try, using Outlook 2007 connecting to Exchange 2013 mailboxes. I do the same from another profile connecting to an Exchange 2010 server and there it works.

Note:
I can see the custom fields have values when I query the events using SOAP calls:

```
 <t:ExtendedProperty>
    <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="TimeTellID" PropertyType="Integer"/>
    <t:Value>10016</t:Value>
 </t:ExtendedProperty>
 <t:ExtendedProperty>
    <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="TimeTellSyncID" PropertyType="String"/>
    <t:Value>000000008[snip]7F63DD0000</t:Value>
 </t:ExtendedProperty>
 <t:ExtendedProperty>
    <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="TimeTellSyncTime" PropertyType="SystemTime"/>
    <t:Value>2014-01-10T09:20:13Z</t:Value>
 </t:ExtendedProperty>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

When doing an Outlook/Exchange synchronization from my Delphi app through OLE I got this EOleException:

```
"A custom field with this name but a different data type already exists. Enter a different name"
```

My code was trying to add a user property of type olInteger with name *TimeTellID*.

So obviously, there already was a *TimeTellID* of a different type.

What I did was remove the field through the dialogs mentioned in the question, then create a new one. At first this did not work. But the tricky part here is that there are two types *number* and *integer* **and you don't see these together in the dropdown**:

[image]

When I chose *integer* the field showed up.
(So I must have made that mistake sometime in the past).

-- Additional information --

While fiddling with this issue I noticed a bit of confusion relating to the user properties being part of the *appointment items* and/or the *folder*.
My code adding the user properties had a third parameter set to false. 
That third parameter is *AddToFolderFields*. Quoting from [UserProperties.Add Method (Outlook)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867389.aspx):

*True if the property will be added as a custom field to the folder that the item is in. This field can be displayed in the folder's view. False if the property will be added as a custom field to the item but not to the folder.*

So by not assigning the user properties to the folder as well, they do not become available in the Outlook dialogs.
Obviously it is possible in Outlook to define them as folder properties 'after the fact' and then the values will be picked up from the appointment properties.